# The border is drawn over the text

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

In the CAPTCHA page, the right border for the box shown on the right side is drawn over the text, not in the correct position.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Same problem, except on the main site. http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/q/3040/24168

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fix is on dev now. It will be in the next production build.

Comment: Will it also be fixed on the main site?

Comment: @Luke yes the fix applies to both main 'n meta.